# typedef in header causes error "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'typedef'"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, header, typedef

Dear wisdom of the internet,

in the header-file (Objective-C)

myTestClass.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>  
@interface myTestClass : NSObject {  
    typedef int pixel;   
}  
- (id) initWithPic: (NSString*) picFileName;  
- (void) dealloc;  
- (void) doSomething;  
@end
```

At the line `typedef int pixel;`xCode complains like
     **( ! ) "Expected specifier-qualifier-list before
'typedef'" ( 3 )**

This err-msg seems pretty popular but given solutions (missing #import) do not work for me.
Also the hints I found do not explain what is going wrong here.

I do not understand this err-msg
Can someone explain it to me?

I do appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, put your should just put the typedef before your interface.

Inside the braces is the place for iVars.

If you want an integer variable, then you do not need the typedef:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    int myPixel;
}
@end
```

Typedefs are used to create a new type, based on another. For instance:

```
typedef int pixel;

@interface MyClass
{
    pixel myPixel;
}
@end
```

So when you use the `pixel`pseudo-type, the `int` type will be used.

Comment: OK, so the code ist correct "just" the place was wrong.  
Should have known that -it is late (europe)-
So I do not care any longer what that err-msg means

I'd like to make my return type humanreadable means just a substitution like in your 2nd example.
  
Thank you for your quick answer